# How can I find a number range inside a piece of text using ElasticSearch

Tags: search, text, elasticsearch

I've been reading through the internet trying to work out how I find a number range in a piece of text using Elastic Search. However I have had no luck.

Here's an example, say I have the following set of documents (note that the document is NOT split into multiple fields it's just a block of text).

doc1{
msg:"I have 7 books"
}

doc2{
msg:"I have 15 books"
}

doc3{
msg:"I have 19 books"
}

Is it possible to form a query using ElasticSearch to find all the people who own between 10 and 20 books?

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ES 1.5, the [`keep_types` token filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keep-types-tokenfilter.html) is designed for this sort of thing, apparently. I set it up (with ES 1.5) in this code, and it seems to work:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/b2c86b748d0c33957df1dcb90a3b405b0a4ca646

However, I didn't actually need that to get it to work. The [standard analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) divides the text into tokens based on whitespace, and so you can then apply the `range` query (a filter works too) against the field and it seems to do what you wanted:

I set up a simple index:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "msg": "I have 7 books" }
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "msg": "I have 15 books" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "msg": "I have 19 books" }
```

Then used a range query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
           "msg": {
              "from": 10,
              "to": 20
           }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "msg": "I have 15 books"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "msg": "I have 19 books"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code for the second example:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/0979803673efb5b7ff063c257efd82617a93bd06

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Sloan. So you're saying that this just worked out of the box? I had tried this using the Java API (1.5) and didn't have any success.  I shall try again this evening. I'll mark your answer as correct once I've confirmed it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't try it with Java, I just ran the code snippets in the "sense" link against a local ES instance (with CORS enabled), and it worked.

Comment: Tested it out and it seemed to work fine, thanks. I did notice other issues though. I changed the query to "gt:10" - this did not produce the results I'd have expected.